# How can I get the selected value of an object in an array on click?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, selecteditem

I have a an array of objects listed in a table, and I'm needing to get the value of the clicked object. When I click on of the numbers, it loops through and only gets the last arrays value.

I'm currently looping through all of the objects in the array, but I can't get it to just pick the one object i select.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(call, index) in filterSummary" :key="index">
          <td>
            <a
              @click="onSelect"
              class="waves-effect waves-dark green btn-small left"
              id="select_DID_button"
            >{{ call.number }}</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ call.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.volume }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.inboundVolume }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.outboundVolume }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.totalDuration | formatDuration }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.inboundDuration | formatDuration }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.outboundDuration | formatDuration }}</td>
          <td>{{ call.dataValues.averageDuration | formatDuration }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
methods: {
    onSelect() {
      var obj = this.$store.state.callerActivitySummary;
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var newNumber = obj[i].number;
        this.$store.commit("updateNumber", newNumber);
        console.log("Number: ", newNumber);
      }
      this.getCallerActivityDetails();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My array of objects looks like this.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
    "alternativeNames": [],
    "number": "012345678",
    "dataValues": {},
    "name": "Random name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Console output is:

```
Number:  111968948
Number:  49819811
Number:  0566561651
Number:  012345678
```

I'm needing to get the number from the clicked object.

Comment: Please show a *complete* code example, include any relevant UI elements.

Comment: Is `obj` reffering to `items`? or the object containing `items`?

Comment: Sorry, obj contains the array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a comparison of the selected number and the number in each objects you're looping over. You need something like this:

```
if (selectedNumber === obj[i].number) {
    this.$store.commit("updateNumber", selectedNumber);
    break;
}
```

Where `selectedNumber` is the number being passed to the method.

```
@click="onSelect(call.number)"
```

...

```
methods: {
    onSelect(selectedNumber) { ...
```

Comment: Correct, it's only grabbing the last value in the array. Changing it to `let` has the same results.

Comment: Seems like you're looping through all the objects and writing to the store each time. Where is the comparison to number selected and the number in the objects you're looping through?

Comment: You'll need something like `if (selected.number === obj[i].number) { this.$store.commit("updateNumber", obj[i].number); break; }`

Comment: So that's grabbing the first item now, how do I set `selected` to the item i click on? Sorry I feel like i'm super tunnel visioned right now on this.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Vue but see my edits. Basically you need to pass the number through `@click` and then add the argument to the `onSelect` method.

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help!